# Enviar para controlador model preenchida

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho na minha página principal duas partial views, cada um delas com uma view model específica associada, onde todos os campos da tela são montados através de Razor, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Área Cliente Aciaria</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodAreaProce, Model.ListaAreaProce, "", new { @id = "ddl-Cod-Area-Proce", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Peso Específico</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VlrPesoEspec, new { @id = "txt-Vlr-Peso-Espec", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "5" })
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2px;"></span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodUnidaMedid, Model.ListaUnidaMedid, "", new { @id = "ddl-Cod-Unida-Medid", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Diâmetro Ideal</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VlrDiametroIdeal, new { @id = "txt-Vlr-Diametro-Ideal", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "4" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-warning" style="margin-top: 25px; padding-left: 20px">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Transicao, new { @id = "chk-Transicao" })
      <label style="padding-left: 0px;">Aço de Transição</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando o usuário acionar o evento salvar, preciso enviar todos os dados preenchidos por ele para o controller através de uma chamada Ajax, sendo que as informações estão distribuídas nas duas models existentes na página.

Qual a forma de enviar este objeto preenchido na View para o controlador?

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

1) Criei um form dentro de cada partial view

@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "AcosInternos", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frm-Detalhes-Acos-Internos"}))

2) Antes da chamada ajax, serializo e converto para Json o conteúdo desse formulário

```
var json = JSON.stringify($('#frm-Detalhes-Acos-Internos').serializeObject());
```

3) Envio via ajax o valor obtido e no controller converto o Json para o tipo viewmodel

```html
$.ajax({
cache: false,
async: true,
type: "POST",
url: '/AcosInternos/Salvar',
dataType: "json",
data: {
   dados: json
}
```

4) No controller, recebo o Json e realizo a conversão

```
public ActionResult Salvar(string dados)
{
    AcoInternoViewModel acoInternoViewModel = this.DeserializarObjeto<AcoInternoViewModel>(dados);
}
```

Comment: Como está o seu controller? Poderia postar como está chamando as partiais?

Comment: Randrade, adicionei nos posts mais informações a respeito da forma como estou fazendo. Queria saber se existe uma forma de passar via ajax a model preenchida, sem necessidade de converter para Json antes, já que da forma que estou fazendo não consigo preencher automaticamente objeto dentro de objetos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o *Ajax.BeginForm* nativo do MVC para fazer o post em ajax.

View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Salvar", "AcosInternos", = new AjaxOptions( HttpMethod = "POST")))
{
//Renderizar campos
}
```

No controller

```
public ActionResult Salvar(AcoInternoViewModel dados)
{
//Código
}
```

Se por outros motivos você não puder utilizar a estrutura nativa, basta mudar o seu código para:

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 async: true,
 type: "POST",
 url: '/AcosInternos/Salvar',
 data: $("#frm-Detalhes-Acos-Internos").serialize(),
 success: function (data) {
    //seu código
 }
});
```

No controller

```
public ActionResult Salvar(AcoInternoViewModel dados)
{
//Código
}
```

**EDIÇÃO 1**

Para adicionais mais campos e passar no formato correto, será necessário mudar o código da serialização.

Antigo

```
$("#frm-Detalhes-Acos-Internos").serialize()
```

Novo

```
var base = $("#frm-Detalhes-Acos-Internos").serializeArray();
base.push({ name: "NovoCampo", value:"Novo Valor" }); 
var data = $.param(base);
```

Comment: Entendi... Se eu precisar de passar outras informações no "data" é possível? No meu caso por exemplo, tenho um angular UI-grd editável na tela e também preciso enviar as informações preenchidas pelo usuário para o controlador no mesmo método

Comment: Neste caso, você tem que utilizar o serializeArray, e depois a função $.param para formatar os dados. Vou editar a minha resposta para colocar um exemplo melhor.

Comment: Neste caso, os dados do grid já estão em formato de array, porem dentro do objeto que é esperado no controller ele é uma lista tipada. Existe a possibilidade de passar apenas esta informação por Json?

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Fernandes,

Estou fazendo uma confusão e tanto... veja se consegue me ajudar.

Tenho duas partial view onde as informações de cadastro estão divididas.

Criei um form (html.beginForm) em cada trecho para agrupar os dados de acordo com seu tipo, por exemplo:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "AcosInternos", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frm-Acos-Internos-Edicao-Dados"}))
            {
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Código Aço</label>
      <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Informacoes.CodIdentAco, Model.Informacoes.ListaSubgrupoAco, "", new { @id = "ddl-SubGrupo-Aco", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2px;"></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.CodAcoNumero, new { @id = "txt-Codigo-Aco", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "3", @style = "width: 50px" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Norma/Descrição Comercial</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.CodIdentNorma, new { @id = "txt-Cod-Ident-Norma", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "4" })
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2px;"></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.NomIdentAco, new { @id = "txt-Nom-Ident-Aco", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "16" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Norma/Descrição Corporativa</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.CodIdentMarca, new { @id = "txt-Cod-Ident-Marca", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "4" })
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2px;"></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.NomIdentMarca, new { @id = "Nom-Ident-Marca", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "16" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Situação</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.Situacao, "A", new {@id="opt-Situacao-Ativo", @checked = true})Ativo</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.Situacao, "I", new {@id="opt-Situacao-Inativo"})Inativo</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.Situacao, "E", new {@id="opt-Situacao-Experiencia"})Experiência</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.Situacao, "P", new {@id="opt-Situacao-Pendente"})Pendente</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Temperaturas Lingotamento</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.TempLingotamento, new { @id = "txt-Vlr-Temp-Lingotamento", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "4" })
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2px;"></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.TempLingotamento2, new { @id = "txt-Vlr-Temp-Lingotamento2", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "4" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Padrão</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Informacoes.Padrao, new { @id = "txt-Padrao", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "4" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Config. Norma Corporativa</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.ConfigNormaCorporativa, "1", new {@id="opt-Norma-Regra-Geral"})1 - Imprimir Via Regra Geral</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.ConfigNormaCorporativa, "2", new {@id="opt-Norma-Aco-Externo"})2 - Imprimir Via Aço Externo</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Informacoes.ConfigNormaCorporativa, "3", new {@id="opt-Norma-Nao-Imprimir", @checked = true})3 - Não Imprimir</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Essas informações do exemplo são relacionadas as informações principais, que é uma classe interna dentro da minha view model.

No momento de realizar a chamada ajax, o método no controlador espera receber um objeto do tipo AcoInternoCadastroViewModel, que é composto por:

```
 /* Dados primários */
 public InformacoesAco Informacoes { get; set; }

 /* Dados Gerais */
 public DetalhesAco Detalhes { get; set; }

 /* Classificações */
 public Classificacao Classificacao { get; set; }
```

Meu problema está na chamada ajax, no momento de preencher este objeto.

1) Estou obtendo os dados de cada formulário:

```html
 var formDados = $('#frm-Acos-Internos-Edicao-Dados');
var formDadosGerais = $('#frm-Acos-Internos-Edicao-DadosGerais :not([name="search_listbox"])');
var formClassificacao = $('#frm-Acos-Internos-Edicao-Classificacao').not(':input[type=hidden]');
```

2) Na chamada ajax, estou tentando passar as informações de N maneiras:

```html
$.ajax({
cache: false,
async: true,
type: "POST",
url: '/AcosInternos/Salvar',
dataType: "json",
```

```html
//data: JSON.stringify({ Informacoes: formDados.serialize(), Detalhes: formDadosGerais.serialize(), Classificacao: formClassificacao.serialize() }),
//data: $.param({ Informacoes: formDados.serializeArray(), Detalhes: formDadosGerais.serialize(), Classificacao: formClassificacao.serialize() }),
//data: JSON.stringify({ Informacoes: formDados.serializeObject(), Detalhes: formDadosGerais.serializeObject(), Classificacao: formClassificacao.serializeObject() }),
```

Mas quando chega no controlador, alguns campos não ficam corretamente preenchidos.

O nome dos campos após a serialização está sendo composto pelo nome da classe interna + o nome da propriedade, exemplo: Informacoes.CodIdentAco.

Estou imaginando que este seja o problema... Se conseguisse retirar o nome da classe interna do nome, poderia converter para Json e serializar novamente no controller.

Qual melhor caminho você sugere?

Obrigado!

Comment: Agora eu entendi melhor do que você precisa, eu achei que você tinha um objeto formado por campos simples (string, int, etc). Vou editar a minha resposta para este caso

Comment: Eu entendi o que está acontecendo, para que o nome do input fique correto você não pode passar o modelo desta forma: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Informacoes.CodIdentAco..), crie uma partial view, e passe o model.Informacoes informações para ela, na view você vai renderizar assim : @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CodIdentAco...), isso vai fazer com que o nome fique correto.